# Regarding SwatchLegend and ColorFunction

Tags: plotting, color, legending

Can I use `ColorFunction` in place of color in `SwatchLegend` or is there any way to include `ColorFunction` in `SwatchLegend`?

For example, the command

```
SwatchLegend[{Directive[{"Rainbow", Opacity[0.25]}]},
  {Text[Style["f1", FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", 18, Red]]}]
```

shows only gray color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update 2:** In version 10.0+, you can also use [`LinearGradientImage`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LinearGradientImage.html):

```
Labeled[LinearGradientImage["Rainbow", ImageSize -> {30, 30}], 
 Style["f1", 18, Red, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"], Top]
```

[image]

**Update:** ***"want the color gradient of "Rainbow" in a single box for single label**"*:

```
Labeled[ImageResize[ColorData["Rainbow", "Image"], {30, 30}], 
 Style["f1", 18, Red, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", ShowStringCharacters -> False], 
 Top]
```

[image]

Use

```
Show[ImageResize[ColorData["Rainbow", "Image"], {30, 30}], BaseStyle -> Opacity[.5]]
```

as the first argument of `Labeled` to get:

[image]

**Original answer:**

```
labels = {"f1", "f2", "f3", "f4"};

SwatchLegend["Rainbow", labels, BaseStyle -> Opacity[.25], LegendMarkerSize -> 30]
```

[image]

```
SwatchLegend["Rainbow", Style[##, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", 18] & @@@ 
  Transpose[{labels, ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ Subdivide[Length@labels - 1]}], 
 BaseStyle -> Opacity[.25], LegendMarkerSize -> 30]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you.. But I want the color gradient of "Rainbow" in a single box for single label..

Comment: @user61823, please see the update.

Comment: How can I use the "Labeled" Command for two images that can be displayed in one column...?? The output will be the same as that of SwatchLegend one having the "Rainbow" color and the other .. say Red.. and the labels will be f1, f2.. at the right position for each color..

Comment: @user61823, you can try something like: `Column[{Labeled[ImageResize[ColorData["Rainbow", "Image"], {30, 30}], 
   Style["f1", 18, Blue, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", 
    ShowStringCharacters -> False], Right], 
  Labeled[Graphics[{Red, Rectangle[]}, ImageSize -> {30, 30}, 
    PlotRangePadding -> 0, ImagePadding -> 0], 
   Style["f2", 18, Red, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", 
    ShowStringCharacters -> False], Right]}, Alignment -> Left]`

Answer (score 1):

```
SeedRandom[0]

data = RandomReal[100, 10]

(* {65.2468, 63.307, 68.2813, 56.6352, 93.5202, 97.6188, 23.8452, \
63.7562, 10.1098, 64.5525} *)

{min, max} = MinMax[data]

(* {10.1098, 97.6188} *)

Format[f[n_]] := Subscript[f, n]

SwatchLegend[
 ColorData["Rainbow"][Rescale[#, {min, max}]] & /@ data,
 f /@ Range[Length[data]],
 LegendLayout -> "Row"]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Or

```
SwatchLegend[ColorData["Rainbow"][#] & /@ Range[0, 1, 1/9], 
 f /@ Range[10], LegendLayout -> "Row"]
```

[image]

**EDIT 2:** It appears from your comment that you want a [`BarLegend`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BarLegend.html) rather than a [`SwatchLegend`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SwatchLegend.html).

```
BarLegend["Rainbow", 
 LegendLabel -> Text[Style["f1", FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", 18, Red]], 
 LegendLayout -> "Row"]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you.. But I want the color gradient of "Rainbow" in a single box for single label..